# Grammatical Dissection of “it is not completed yet”

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives

Look at the following sentence.

> It is not completed yet.

I think the sentence is in passive voice as the word **“completed”** is a verb. So, if I add an object in the sentence, it would be:

> It is not yet completed by him.

In active voice:

> He did not complete it yet.

What is the sense of **“yet”** here?

Also, if someone has assigned me a task, and I haven’t completed it yet, should I say **“It is not yet complete”** or former?

Comment: Yes, "completed" is a verb in your example. But it's ungrammatical: a passive VP is required as in "It has not been completed yet". The nearest active equivalent is "x has not completed it yet". "Yet" means 'up to the time of the utterance'. Note that "completed" is only an adjective when it's a pre-head modifier of a noun, as in "Please submit your [completed application] within 14 day", and even there a case could be made for analysing it as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

*Complete* can be either a verb or an adjective. It would be more natural to say

> It is not complete yet (adjective) - or
>
> It has not been completed yet (verb, passive).
>
> He has not (I have not) completed it yet (verb, active).

In all these cases, *yet* means *up to and including the present time.*

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *is not completed* can be a passive verb phrase; but if it is, it is present simple, and so it would refer to an act of completing, not a resulting state; furthermore, since it is present simple not present continuous, in most contexts it would refer to something habitual.

So as a verb phrase, *It is not completed* means something like *It does not (generally, or normally) get completed* - something that might be said, but not very commonly. I haven't been able to think of a plausible example of it.

However, like many past participles, *completed* can also be an adjective, describing the state that results from completing. In that sense *It is not completed yet* is fine: it is not yet in the state "completed".

*Complete* is more common than *completed* as the adjective, but both are po9ssible, and in this context I can't find any difference in meaning.